# Error in detaching and attaching objects in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I get the object, using NoTracking, convert and manipulate it, send it to an asp.net mvc view. I get back an edited version, call the edit method in my repository, try to Attach it, it throws the following error:

`An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`

How I get the data:

```
IQueryable<User> query = db.Users.AsNoTracking();
```

How I edit the data:

```
    public User UpdateUser(User user, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<User, object>>> properties)
    {
            db.Users.Attach(user); //Error happens right here.
            foreach (var selector in properties)
            {
                string propertyName = Helpers.PropertyToString(selector.Body);
                db.Entry(user).Property(propertyName).IsModified = true;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return user;
    }
```

When I get the entities using `AsNoTracking`, shouldn't that detach the thing for me? Even if it didn't detach, the whole asp.net life cycle is supposed to be restarted on resubmitting the data, which would make the graph empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

I do my bindings like this:

```
DbContext db = new DbContext("ConnStringName");
Bind<IUserRepository>().To<SqlServerUserRepository>()
                .WithConstructorArgument("db", db);
```

Comment: Does your User object have a collection of children? I recently ran into an issue where attaching the parent object with two new children caused this error. The children both had null ID fields, thus the "same key" error.

Comment: @Ed Chapel Not the one I sent to the `UpdateUser` method. The model has children yes, but those are already in the database.

Comment: Ok. Is your db context stored in the session or application? Or do you create a new instance on every request?

Comment: I created it in the global.ascx file. I use DI to inject the context in every repository inside a ninject module. So I'm not quite sure if it lives for the whole app or it creates one on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your db context is created once and that instance is effectively a singleton. When you attempt to attach the `User`, the context detects that it already has one in the cache and fails.

I recommend changing the context to be created per request. With Ninject, you can bind it with

```
Bind<YourDbContext>().ToMethod(context => CreateContext()).InRequestScope();
```

where `YourDbContext` is the type of the `db` variable and `CreateContext()` is the method in your global.ascx.

**UPDATE**

You are indeed creating your database context once and storing it as a singleton. No worries, you can set up your bindings as

```
// DbContext db = new DbContext("ConnStringName");
Bind<DbContext>().ToMethod(context => new DbContext("ConnStringName")).InRequestScope();
Bind<IUserRepository>().To<SqlServerUserRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

This will create a new DbCOntext for each Request and prevent the cached `User` from colliding with the submitted `User` when attaching.

Comment: Ed, could you help me with how my bindings are setup. I'm not sure how to use your bindings. I edited my question with how I did my bindings.